# Error in nextTick: "TypeError: path.split is not a function"

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuelidate

I have got a weird issue while using **vuelidate**.

I have this array of Objects for example defined in the data():

```
arrOfObj = [{a: 1},{b: 2},{c: 3}]
```

What I tried to do is to add 'Required'(vuelidate) attribute to this array of objects like this:

validations(){

```
let array = this.arrOfObj;
let result = array.map(function(obj){return Object.assign(obj, {required: true})})
console.log("New Array: ", result);

return {
    indexKey: {
        required
    },
    defValues: result //Here is where I think the issue is
}
```

},

Only when adding this row:

```
 defValues: result //Here is where I think the issue is
```

I get this error:

> Error in nextTick: "TypeError: path.split is not a function"

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does mean `required` prop for `indexKey`, where it comes from?

Comment: Required from Vuelidate library

Comment: I mean `{ required }` is invalid object if required is not defined like in your example.

Comment: You want to go over chat I would like to explain it more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

Try leaving out the `:true` аssignment to use your import instead:

```
Object.assign(obj, {required})
```

Perhaps your `defaultValue` expects strings, not objects. Or it expects a string member called `path` in the object.

One other issue.

Your object.assign is overwriting your source.  Use an empty object to initialize, or a spread operator.

```js
let result = array.map(function(obj){
 return Object.assign({}, obj, {required: true})
})
```

```js
let result = array.map(function(obj){
 return {...obj, required: true}
})
```

Comment: I got this error and have no idea what that means:
[Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "TypeError: path.split is not a function"

Comment: I do see that required has been added to the array of objects.. can't figure this out

Comment: The error means that somewhere you code is calling something like `anObject.path.split(',')`. But `path` is not a string with a function called `split`.

Comment: does the error have a code file, line, and position?

Comment: i added another possible tweak to solution